# Netflix show with elemental monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was this show I think on Netflix and they each had like elemental monsters and the water ones were like really technologically advanced. And one charcter had this dark one that was like a voodoo doll.

The elements were like water, fire, air, dark, light.

Comment: Is it Animated?   Is it Anime?  Any further details?

Comment: Were the "monsters" the protagonists? Villains? Allies?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Where you were when you watched it might help (assuming none of the below are correct).  Netflix has access to different series depending on your country.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say with so little information, but could it be Netflix's *[The Dragon Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_Prince)*?

> The series is set in a fantasy world on the continent of Xadia, which is rich with magic derived from six primal elements: The Sun, the Moon, the Stars, the Earth, the Sky and the Ocean. However, the humans - who could not utilize primal magic - discovered the use of dark magic, which is fueled by the life essence of animals and magical creatures. As a consequence, they were driven off by the dragons and elves of Xadia to the other end of the continent, where they founded the five human kingdoms. The Breach, the border between the two halves of the continent, was guarded by Thunder, the king of dragons.
>
> Now, after humans killed the dragon king and his egg, war is imminent. The elves attempt to assassinate the human king Harrow and his heir, the young prince Ezran, in retaliation for the egg's destruction. One among the elves, the young Rayla, along with Ezran and his older half-brother Callum, discovers that the dragon king's egg wasn't in fact destroyed, but stolen by the mage Viren, King Harrow's advisor. Together they undertake to return the egg to the dragons to prevent war between the humans and elves. But Viren, intent on conflict, seizes power after the king dies in the assassination attempt, and sends his children Claudia and Soren after the fugitives to kill the princes and recover the egg at all costs.

As per [the wiki entry](https://dragonprince.fandom.com/wiki/Magic#Primal_Sources), the creatures of the world are inherently tied to the elements:

> All magic in the world draws upon the six Primal Sources. These are enormous, powerful entities of the natural world: the Sun, the Moon, the Stars, the Earth, the Sky, and the Ocean. A mage can draw upon these Sources to cast different spells; for example, drawing from the Sky's Primal Magic allows a mage to cast wind and thunderstorm spells. The magical creatures of Xadia are all connected to a Primal Source, and as such, their powers and abilities reflect that source.[2](https://dragonprince.fandom.com/wiki/Magic#Primal_Sources) Each magical creature in Xadia possesses a connection with their source, called an arcanum. This is described by Lujanne as "the secret of the Primal, or its meaning."

### Trailer

Answer (score 2):

After rereading your question, I think it's likely you're looking for a series where the characters use monsters to battle, in which case *[Kaijudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo)* is a good match, and is currently on Netflix.

> The series follows the adventures of a young boy named Ray Okamoto from San Campion who possesses the rare ability to summon and duel alongside fantastical creatures from a parallel dimension. Ray and his two best friends Allie and Gabe join the ranks of the mysterious Duel Masters to ensure the survival of both races.

For [the technologically advanced water creatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kaijudo_characters#Water_Civilization):

> The Water Civilization is located within a large body of water. The creatures of the Water Civilization are the most centered and peaceful. They don't start battles, but when provoked they will retaliate in full force. The artifact of the Water Civilization is the Helm of Ultimate Technology, which can be used by anyone who is mentally-skilled to telepathically control any creature in the Water Civilization.

### Meet the Masters - Ray